# Link sniffing - http get response codes wrong

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, http-status-codes

I have the task to go trough around 200k links and check the status code of their responses. Anything other than 2xx would mean a problem which means that link has to be manually checked (added to a DB later).

The links I have from a DB and are both http and https, some of them are not valid (e.g. ww.fyxs.d). The format I get is JSON and it's something like this

```
{
    "id": xxx,
    "url": xxxx
}
```

I went with a really simple solution which unfortunately doesn't work.

I am taking the links from a json file and then starting from the back sending a http/https.get request, waiting for the response, checking and processing the status code and moving to the next link after removing the previous one from the list to preserve memory. The problem is that I keep getting 4xx almost all the time and if I do a GET from a REST client I get a 200 OK.

I don't know if it's possible but I only need the correct status code and the body I'm not interested in hence the HEAD method. I also tried with 
`method: 'GET'` - still wrong status codes and `http/https.request` - I don't even get a response.

Here is my code:

```js
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var urlMod = require('url');

var links = require('./links_to_check.json').links_to_check;

var callsRemaining = links.length;
var current = links.length - 1;

startQueue();

function startQueue(){
 getCode(links[current].url);
 current--;
}

function getCode(url){
 var urlObj = urlMod.parse(url);
 var options = {
  method: 'HEAD',
  hostName: urlObj.host,
  path: urlObj.path
 };
 var httpsIndex = url.indexOf('https');
 if(httpsIndex > -1 && httpsIndex < 5){
  https.get(options,function(response){
   proccessResponse(response.statusCode);
  }).on('error', (e) => {
   startQueue();
  });
 }else{
  if(url.indexOf('http:') < 0) return;
  http.get(options,function(response){
   proccessResponse(response.statusCode);
  }).on('error', (e) => {
   startQueue();
  });
 }
}

function proccessResponse(responseCode){ 
 console.log("response => " + responseCode);
 if(responseCode != 200){
  errorCount++;
 }
 ResponseReady();
}

function ResponseReady(){
 --callsRemaining;
 if(callsRemaining <= 0){
  //Proccess error when done
 } 
 links.pop();
 startQueue();
}
```

I would really appreciate some help - when we succeed I will publish it as a module so if someone needs to check a set of links they can just use it :)

After we solve this I was thinking of using async.map and splitting the links to chunks and running the analysis in parallel so it's faster. The current process written in shell takes around 36 hours.

Comment: What 4xx code is this? I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, so maybe you should consider simplifying it and giving a single example that gives you an error code but should be a 200 OK.

Comment: Why not try `method: 'GET'`. If the server doesn't support `HEAD` option, you might end up getting 4XX

Comment: Why not use an already written node module like https://www.npmjs.com/package/broken-link

Comment: I'd be interested to see at least one 4xx response if possible and check for CORS issue...

Comment: @Searching - There is no CORS enforcement from node.js.

Comment: @Mottie - I tried with the module it works really nice, but it also says the link is broken although I copy paste it in a REST client and I get a 200OK. It is also a bit slow but I guess when I run them in parallel it will be fine.

Comment: @Searching - as I mentioned I tried it, but I still get bad status codes

Comment: are you able to share the entire 4xx error for the request that passed in the REST client and failed in the program ?

Comment: `{
"createdAt":"2016-12-19T22:35:39.193Z",
"version":"8.19.60.296",
"kind":"ARC#SavedDataExport",
"requests":[
{
"url":"http://www.sehir.edu.tr/en/Pages/Academic/Bolum.aspx?BID=20",
"method":"GET",
"headers":"",
"payload":"",
"name":"fds",
"type":"google-drive",
"driveId":"0B8CgAXoZ6PkVWUhqLU05MWJuZ2c",
"updated":1482186927643,
"kind":"ARC#RequestData"
}
]
}`

Comment: Doesn't seem like you need to set the `path` if using parse which returns a complete `urlObject` https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost . When I tested, this page it worked on removal of `path` from the `options`

Comment: @Searching - I need to check the link as is, including the path and query strings. Would removing the path from options only check the [host](www.sehir.edu.tr) ? 
As I was monitoring the process yesterday I noticed that a lot of the links do redirects after a 302 (moved permanently or something similar) so maybe my solution was working and was showing the correct codes. The broken-link module had a option to check for redirect and this brought the broken links down, but I guess if you reach 200 in the end it's fine. I would like to do it simpler than the module so it's faster.